# Mongo Node driver how to get all fields of $max aggregate from an array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection called "products" which has an array of "bids" objects.

I want to find out the Maximum bid for each product, for this I am aggregating Products on $max with $bids.bidamount field. However this is only giving me the largest bid amount. How do I project all the bid fields for the max aggregation.

Here is a sample document

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58109a5138fe12215cfdc064"),
"product_id" : 2,
"item_name" : "Auction Item1",
"item_description" : "Test",
"seller_name" : "ak@gmail.com",
"item_price" : "20",
"item_quantity" : 7,
"sale_type" : "Auction",
"posted_at" : "2016:10:26 04:58:09",
"expires_at" : "2016:10:30 04:58:09",
"bids" : [ 
    {
        "bid_id" : 1,
        "bidder" : "ak@gmail.com",
        "bid_amount" : 300,
        "bit_time" : "2016:10:26 22:36:29"
    }, 
    {
        "bid_id" : 2,
        "bidder" : "ak@gmail.com",
        "bid_amount" : 100,
        "bit_time" : "2016:10:26 22:37:29"
    }
],
"orders" : [ 
    {
        "buyer" : "ak@gmail.com",
        "quantity" : "2"
    }, 
    {
        "buyer" : "ak@gmail.com",
        "quantity" : "3"
    }
]
```

}

Here is my mongo query:

```
  db.products.aggregate([
   {
     $project: {

       bidMax: { $max: "$bids.bid_amount"}
        }
   }
    ])
```

which gives the following result:

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("58109a5138fe12215cfdc064"),
    "bidMax" : 300
}
```

Comment: Did you try adding bid fields to the project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.products.aggregate([{$unwind:"$bids"},{$group:{_id:"$_id", sum:{$sum:"$bids.bid_amount"}}},{$project:{doc:"$$ROOT", _id:1, sum:1}, {$sort:{"sum":-1}},{$limit:1}]),
```

which return something like { "_id" : ObjectId("5811b667c50fb1ec88227860"), "sum" : 600, doc:{your document....} }

Comment: This seems to project the highest bid alongwith the original product_id.

Can you please explain the working of piped commands? Also, If I need to project more than just the id, where do I place the additional field names in this.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
db.products.aggregate([{
    $unwind: '$bids'
  }, {
    $group: {
      _id: '$products_id',
      maxBid: {
        $max: '$bids.bid_amount'
      }
    }
  }])
```

Comment: This still returns :

{
    "_id" : null,
    "maxBid" : 300
}

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collectionName.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$product_id",
           maxBidAmount: { $max: "$bids.bid_amount" }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

Hey use this query, you will get the result.

Comment: This returns all the bids but I want the all fields for the max bid.

{
    "_id" : 2,
    "maxBidAmount" : [ 
        300, 
        100
    ]
}